# get_feature_names() there is an attribure error

Tags: python, nlp

```
vocab = vectorizer.get_feature_names()
print(vocab)
```

AttributeError: 'CountVectorizer' object has no attribute 'get_feature_names'. Did you mean: 'get_feature_names_out'?

I tried to change the code and use the same with corpus. Also, I updated `sklearn` but it does not work

Comment: What doesn't work? `get_feature_names_out()`? you need to provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that corpus is a piece of text from a text file, to get the feature names of a `CountVectorizer` object, you need to use the `get_feature_names_out()` method instead of the `get_feature_names()`. This is because according to the error message `get_feature_names()` is not a valid method of the `CountVectorizer` object.

Here's an example code that should work:

```py
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

corpus = ["This is the first document.", "This is the second document.", "And this is the third one."]
vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)

vocab = vectorizer.get_feature_names_out()
print(vocab)
```